# How to render a specific view from a different PageModel file

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

From `page1.cshtml.cs`, how do I render the contents of `page2.cshtml`?

I am not looking for redirection as I don't want the url address to change.

Comment: Are you wanting to include `page2` in `page1`, or completely replace the contents of `page1` with `page 2` (in which case, make a submit and use `return View(`page2", yourModel);` instead of `return RedirectToAction(..);`)

Comment: Yes, I want to replace totally. Can I still use `View` in Asp.net Core Razor Pages?

Comment: My comment was for core-mvc (did not notice you also tagged it razor-pages). Its `return Page()` for razor-pages, but not sure if you can return a different page using that.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible at all. Just out of interest, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: For a particular page, I just want to swop out the content. I could put a conditional in the page to render different portions, but I was wondering there's something like `return Page("anotherPage")` just like `View`.